# How to map java class to SQL view without id in spring data jpa?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Here's my class

```
public class JobSteps {

    private String jobNo;

    private String stepNumber;

    private String stepDescription;

}
```

And here's my view

```
JobNo CHAR(7),
StepNumber TEXT,
StepDescription TEXT
```

I tried to annotate my class with Entity, specifying the table name, but spring keeps complaining about id, I added `@Id` to JobNo, but spring complains about type. Is there a way to manage it? I have no access to the view and can't change anything there.

Answer (score 0):

Fo example, You can add JobStepId class and wrap tit with your char column.

```
@Embeddable
class JobStepId implements Serializable {
   String jobIdString;
   Integer jobId;

   //implements equals and hashCode
}
```

Then your class could imbed it:

```
@IdClass(JobStepId.class)
public class JobSteps {
    @Id
    private JobStepId jobNo;

    private String stepNumber;

    private String stepDescription;

}
```